# Exporting R-leaflet applications as html with full source code

Tags: javascript, html, r, leaflet

since updating my R verison, R-leaflet applications exported (e.g via `saveWidget(map, "map.html", selfcontained = T)` don't show the full source code any more but instead reverence different parts of the code via

```
<script src="data:application/javascript;base64,somescribbeling"></script>
```

However, I would like to alter some parts of the css code embedded. Is there a way to export he file with the full source code or to easily alter the code embedded within the referenced script files?